# Split in string and join words under Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split and capture the 4 words in a sentence and encountered this error: empty separator?

My codes

```
s1 = input("Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas:") s1 = s1.split(sep = '') print (s1[4])
```

Thank you for any advices!

Comment: The separator is empty (great error message). You need a space in the separator.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
s1 = input("Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas:")
s1 = s1.split(sep = ',')
print (s1)
```

you didnt have the, in sep==""
hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

there's two error in your code
you may change `s1=s1.split()`, this will split your words.
and at the end of your code, I think you want to print the lest world?
if so, you may be `print(s1[2])`
because the python count the list from 0, the first one is 0, the third one is 2,
due to your input is 3 words, so the length of the list is 3.you can also `print(s1[-1])`, it always print out the last one.

Answer (score 0):

For it not to be an empty separator, you should insert a comma inside the two quotes, or else it will technically be empty. In fact, you don't even need the sep because you could just do .split(",")